# onChange Input with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, file

I have this code:

```
<input type="file" onchange="showUrl(this.value)" name="upload[]" multiple="multiple">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon icon-plus"></i> Add file</button></span>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload"><br><br><span id="url"></span>
```

and this javascript function

```
function showUrl(url) {
   document.getElementById("url").innerHTML = url;
}
```

I want to show the url of every file that the user selects with "input file" button. The function shows only the url of the first file. Someone can help me?
Thanks

Comment: @teemu i write php in the title because i use php with js:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showUrl() {
    var allFiles = document.getElementById("myFiles");

    if ('files' in allFiles) {
        if (allFiles.files.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < allFiles.files.length; i++) {
                document.getElementById("url").innerHTML += "<br />"+allFiles.files[i].name;
// note you can mess with proprieties here, like 'size'
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <input type="file" onchange="showUrl()" name="upload[]" id="myFiles" multiple="multiple">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon icon-plus"></i> Add file</button></span>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload">
    <br /><br />
    <span id="url"></span>
</body>
```

Comment: @hteo it doesn't work or it doesn't fit your needs? I'll edit with the output I am receiving (which works!)

Comment: I also use Chrome,but the code shows only one path...I really don't understand

Comment: @hteo try hitting Ctrl+Shift+J, this popups up the console. See what error/warning it gives when you try the code and post here :)

Comment: Unfortunately,the console is empty. Try yourself http://www.unishare.it/corsi/164/materiale  Click on "Carica file" and then "Aggiungi file".

Comment: Are you usign the above script in the site? Because... it's working here. Now tryed with Firefox 40.0.2. I'll edit once more to show you in your page.

Comment: I understand now. I select all the files together,while you select the file one by one. If I want select the files all together?

Comment: Sorry, now I understood. Gonna edit one more time (will look like a complete new answer)

Answer (score 2):

First, change your input to:

`<input type="file" onchange="showUrl(this)" name="upload[]" multiple="multiple">`

Then, change your JS to:

```
function showUrl(url) { 
  for(var i = 0; i < url.files.length; i++) { 
    document.getElementById("url").innerHTML += url.files[i].name; 
  } 
}
```

That way you will be able to read all files selected on the files input.

Comment: No,if I write function showUrl(url) {
 for(var i = 0; i < url.length; i++)
   {
 document.getElementById("url").innerHTML = document.getElementById("file-element").files[i];
   }
}  I get "undefined"

Comment: @hteo: I edited my answer to better fit your question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get the full path, but you can get the file's name by passing `this.files` instead of `this.value`

```
function showUrl(url) {
   for(var i = 0; i < url.length; i++)
   {
       document.getElementById("url").innerHTML += url[i].name + "<br>";
   }
}
```

Comment: With your method the result is (almost correct):                                                                     [object File]                                                                                         [object File]

Comment: Sorry, forgot to access `name` property in `url[i]`. Should be working now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what you're after. try:

```
function showUrl(url) {
   document.getElementById("url").innerHTML += url;
}
```